# How do I obtain Windows command line report of total committed memory (commit charge)?

Tags: command-line, memory, script, windows-server-2003, commit-charge

I want to have a small batch script which runs on a server and every hour logs memory statistics. I already have the script log the process-specific info I want via other tools, but I want to know of a way (either directly on cmd or via a program) which will output the total committed memory of the system. In other words, I think the **commit charge total** statistic in the Task Manager is what I want to know, but via the command line:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instantiate and use the [**Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class for this via VBScript:

```
Set wmiObject = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory=@")
Wscript.Echo "CommitLimit  (B): " & wmiObject.CommitLimit
Wscript.Echo "CommitLimit (MB): " & (wmiObject.CommitLimit / 1048576)
Wscript.Echo "CommittedBytes  (B): " & wmiObject.CommittedBytes
Wscript.Echo "CommittedBytes (MB): " & (wmiObject.CommittedBytes / 1048576)
```

Save with a name like **GetMem.vbs** and invoke using `cscript //Nologo GetMem.vbs`. The class can also be used via the `wmic` command as mentioned below, although of course a script provides you much more flexibility.

Comment: Hi!). `CommitLimit` not a `Commit Charge Peak`

Comment: @STTR: He wants Commit Charge Total. Isn't that the same as CommittedBytes? The values certainly seem to match on my PC.

Comment: http://blog.whatsupduck.net/2010/05/querying-peak-commit-bytes-with.html it not : `wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory get CommittedBytes, CommitLimit`

Comment: @STTR: That blog post you linked to agrees with me. CommittedBytes *is* Commit Charge Total. Neither the OP nor I mentioned Commit Charge Peak, so I honestly fail to see what the problem is.

Comment: Plz, see test script.

Comment: @STTR: Thanks a lot though for reminding me of the `wmic` command. Somehow I always turn to VBS/WSH first and forget about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory get CommittedBytes, CommitLimit
```

Test script ...

These values ​​may be equal so long until RAM exhaustible (CommitLimit and PeakCommitment*(page size))

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

## Peak ...

[Querying Peak Commit Bytes with Powershell (via NtQuerySystemInformation)](http://blog.whatsupduck.net/2010/05/querying-peak-commit-bytes-with.html)

[image]

[image]

Comment: The OP wants *Total*, not *Peak*. I must confess I still don't see what you're driving at.

Comment: @Karan Well, OP wanted to Peak). It is best to use `perfmon` and save the results in a database. Let the OP will clarify the question)

Comment: Karan is correct. It is currently the total (not peak) I am interested in. Also, I would add a link to that article in your answer so others know what you're referring to when you use the "PeakCommitment.ps1" command in your screenshots

Comment: @AlexanderBird script at Querying Peak Commit Bytes with Powershell (via NtQuerySystemInformation) article